# Proving continuity for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am having difficulty in proving the following problem.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Let $f:[0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that for each $y \in [0,1]$, $f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous and for each $ x \in [0,1]$, $f(x,\cdot)$ is measurable.  Assume that $f$ is also bounded.  Show that the function $F(x) = \int_{[0,1]}f(x,y)\,dy$ is continuous for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Dear @user0430 I see that, although you have already asked 18 question in this site and received answers in most of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Write $f_x(y) := f(x,y)$, then $F(x) = \int_0^1 f_x(y)dy$. For any $x_0 \in [0,1]$, as $x \to x_0$, $f_x \to f_{x_0}$ pointwise by continuity along the horizontal lines. Since $|f_x|$ is uniformly bounded for all $x$, we have by the DCT that
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0}F(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0}\int_0^1 f_x(y)dy = \int_0^1 \lim_{x \to x_0}f_x(y)dy = \int_0^1 f_{x_0}(y)dy = F(x_0)
$$